# Won't keychain --clear in .bash_profile interfere with cron jobs?

Tags: security, cron, keychain

[Keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) [tutorials](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-passwordless-login-with-keychain-for-scripts/) recommend adding `/usr/bin/keychain --clear` to ~/.bash_profile to only allow cron jobs to use passwordless login.

I'm not sure I understand how this works. If I take it right, the option will clear the ssh-agent's cache when a user logs in. But in typical keychain setup there's only one ssh-agent running; and the same ssh-agent is used by cron jobs that require passwordless login to other servers. So until the just-logged-in user enters passphrases to unlock the keys, these cron jobs won't be able to run?